# How do I install hiphop-php in CentOS 6?

Tags: centos, curl

I've been trying to install hiphop-php on CentOS 6 with no luck.  I found an .rpm for it but it fails dependency checks on boost which fails to install because it depends on curl which fails to install because it can't overwrite /etc/lib64/libcurl.so.4

I can't remove the current curl version because half the system seems to depend on it.

Has anybody had any luck doing this? It's driving me mad.  I tried compiling from source but that's even more hellish and I really have no idea what I'm doing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following what it says on [this](http://php.webtutor.pl/en/2011/04/22/howto-install-hiphop-for-php-on-centos-5-x/) website.

If you are getting library conflicts, you can use symlinks to resolve them.